# 0 I need help in jolt transformation to convert array of map to array of array

Tags: json, jolt

I have an array of map as input and i need output as array of array when inner array values should be values of input map.

**Input** :

```json
{
  "items": [{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 1
  }, {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 2
  }]
}
```

and I am expecting output as

**Output** :

```json
{
  "items": [
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[#2]" // &2   -> replicates the key "items"
                        // [#2] -> array-wisely loops through the indexes of the "items" array
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]